# goimports behaves differently when called from emacs

Tags: emacs, go

I'm observing a puzzling behaviour of the `goimports` command called from emacs. I'm using the svgo go package, and a minimal program example in the doc imports `"github.com/ajstarks/svgo`"

The code works fine. The `goimports` command is a "Tool to fix (add, remove) your Go imports automatically". Since the `"github.com/ajstarks/svgo"` is needed, I don't expect `goimports` to remove it. And it's true when I call it from the terminal:

```
$ head gg.go 

package main

import (
    "os"
    "github.com/ajstarks/svgo"
)


func main() {
```

then:

```
$ goimports gg.go | head

package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/ajstarks/svgo"
)

func main() {
```

as expected, it just rearranged the imports following the "first the standard library, then the external packages". Now the funny part: **when I call `goimports` from emacs, it deletes the `"github.com/ajstarks/svgo"` line!** (and the program no longer compiles).

Here's (the relevant part of) my .init file:

```
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/go/bin" exec-path))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/go/bin")

(defun my-go-mode-hook ()
  (setq gofmt-command "goimports")  ; Use goimports instead of go-fmt
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save))

(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'my-go-mode-hook)
```

If I comment the `(setq gofmt-command "goimports")` line, the `svgo` import doesn't get deleted.

How's this possible?

Comment: Dies your emacs inherit or use the same GOPATH as your current session where you called goimport manually? And could you try a go install of your little program first, and then switch back to Emacs to see if the issue persists?

Comment: `$ export GOPATH=/usr/local/go/src && emacs` and try again